# Use snpStats with R version 3.0.1

Tags: r

I am trying to use the package `snpStats` with R version 3.0.1. When I use the command, I get the error

```
Warning message:
package ‘snpStats’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

However, when I look on the snpStats documentation, under details, I see this information:

```
Details
Package: snpStats
Version: 1.5.6
Date: 2012-03-27
Depends: R(>= 2.10.0), survival, methods, Matrix
Imports: graphics, grDevices, methods, stats, survival, utils, Matrix
Suggests: hexbin
License: GPL-3
URL: http://www-gene.cimr.cam.ac.uk/clayton
Collate: ss.R contingency.table.R convert.R compare.R glm-test.R imputation.R indata.R long.R misc.R ld.R mvtests.R pedﬁle.R outdata.R plink.R qc.R qq-chisq.R single.R tdt-single.R structure.R xstuff.R zzz.R
LazyLoad: yes
biocViews: Microarray, SNP, GeneticVariability
Packaged: 2012-03-27
Built: R 2.14.1; i686-pc-linux-gnu; 2012-03-27 13:27:08 UTC; unix
```

Doesn't `Depends: R(>= 2.10.0), survival, methods, Matrix` mean that it should run on R x64 on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you may be using `install.packages()`? Or trying to install an older version?

Try following the instructions on the Bioconductor site:
http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/snpStats.html

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("snpStats")
```